# How to acces the CPU and graphics card model in C++

Tags: c++

How can I access the CPU and graphics card model in C++?
I did a lot of research but could not find clear information.

Comment: This is OS  and hardware dependent question. CPU and GPU info in linux is a simple command that can be run. For windows you may have to query harware info.

Comment: Standard `c++` does not have this information. This will be OS dependent.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I will consider your answers.

Comment: You'll need to know platform specifics because not all CPUs are standardized.  There may Systems on a chip which have a variety of configurations.  Likewise with CPU and graphics  cards.